# Host command providing wrong twitter IP address

Tags: ip, host, ipv4

I'm building a clone of the `host` command. I've tried finding the host of `twitter.com` and have received the same IP-Address both on my version and the real `host` command. The address is: `104.244.42.65`.

For some reason, when I input this IP-Address into the browser, it says that there's no webpage with that IP address. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The `host` command uses ICMP to detect if the DNS name of the host can be resolved and host is reachable. And you can resolve and reach the IP that resolved for twitter.com.

However, the web server of Twitter is probably configured to answer only if asked by DNS name and when your browser sends a HTTP GET request with the IP, the server does not respond.

Twitter gets tons of requests per minute. The surely use load-balancers that redirect "twitter.com" to multiple IP addresses and they don't want people to use particular IP addresses, which would mess up their load balancers.